# IDE for XSLT stylesheets

Tags: xml, xslt, ide

What is the best IDE for creating and debugging complex XSLT stylesheets?

For debugging, the ability to set breakpoints and step through the source would be great.

I am interested in all options both commercial and free.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Editors worth checking out:

- Visual Studio
- Altova's [StyleVision/XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/)
- [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/)
- [StylusStudio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xslt_editor.html)

All have their specific advantages, so just check them out. If you already have Visual Studio, I'd suggest you just getting started with this one.

Answer (score 4):

I use Visual Studio. It lets you set breakpoints (conditional or otherwise) and establish watches on whatever XPath expression you can come up with. It also supports XSLT right out the box and colours it differently than regular XML so developing in it is very easy.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is XMLSpy, but isn't free - http://www.altova.com/products/xmlspy/xmlspy.html

If you looking for free, you can try NetBeans - http://www.netbeans.org/

Comment: I have used both and agree with the above recommendation.  If you are a dabbling in XML as part of other work (i.e. java programming) then you can make due quite well with NetBeans.  However, if you are doing XML development as your main task then you really should invest in XMLSpy.

Answer (score 1):

I got a recommendation from someone here for [Altova XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/), and it was pretty nice for the few days I used it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been happy with using XML Cooktop for light XSL development. It's free and has been fairly reliable for me.

Comment: cooktop looks cool, but do you know if it has XSLT 2.0 support?

Answer (score 0):

XML Spy is the best I've used, without question.  But it's very expensive.

I think XSLT debugging and single-stepping is really overrated.  Granted, when I started using XSLT there *were* no debuggers, so I might just be identifying with my torturers here.  But the same things that make writing XSLT often feel as difficult as driving a car while wearing a straitjacket (e.g., variables don't) also make using a debugger not a whole lot more useful than the insert-print-statement paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend **[Liquid Studio](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-studio)**.

For XSLT transformations you can even go for their quite functional *Community Edition*. It lacks many features present in commercial editions like:

- Diagram View
- Graphical View
- Web Services Tools
- XPath Tools
- Debuggers
- Refactoring
- XML Schema Documentation and XML Document Generator
- Visual Studio Extension
- XML Differencing, etc.

BUT still *Community Edition* is cool enough as an editor for **XML (WSDL, XSLT, XQuery, DTD, CSS, XDR, XML Schema, JSON)** with:

- Autocompletion (based on schema)
- Code colouring
- Collapsible sections
- Spellchecker (grammar and XML validation)

Community edition also starts as a 15-days trial so you can evaluate those paid features before deciding on edition.

If you really need XSLT debugging then your option would be *XML Editor Edition*. Though *Community Edition* still allows for smooth transformations while being able to work with source, target and style files in the same IDE.

You can find more details [here](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-studio-editions).

Hope this helps.